# Angular. Обращение к элементу модели

Tags: массивы, angularjs, model

Сервер возвращает данные в модель ангуляра

```
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.pageData = response;
})
```

`response` имеет вид:

```
array(5) {  
    [0]=>  array(3) {    ["order"]=>    string(1) "1"  ["isDone"]=>    bool(true)    ["title"]=>    string(41) "Title1"  }  
    [1]=>  array(3) {    ["order"]=>    int(2)         ["isDone"]=>    bool(false)   ["title"]=>    string(65) " Title2"  }  
    [2]=>  array(3) {    ["order"]=>    int(3)         ["isDone"]=>    bool(false)   ["title"]=>    string(49) " Title3"  }  
    [3]=>  array(3) {    ["order"]=>    int(4)         ["isDone"]=>    bool(false)   ["title"]=>    string(37) " Title4"  }  
    [4]=>  array(3) {    ["order"]=>    int(5)         ["isDone"]=>    bool(false)   ["title"]=>    string(42) " Title5"  } 
}
```

Как во вьюхе обратится к нужному элементу по индексу?

Например `<input ng-model='pageData[2]["isDone"]'/>` - ничего

Comment: `response имеет вид` - это в php он такой, а как он выглядит в json? просто выведите в консоль и посмотрите

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["order"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["isDone"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["title"]=>
    string(41) "Title1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["order"]=>
    int(2)
    ["isDone"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["title"]=>
    string(65) "Title2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["order"]=>
    int(3)
    ["isDone"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["title"]=>
    string(49) "Title3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["order"]=>
    int(4)
    ["isDone"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["title"]=>
    string(37) "Title4"
  }
...
  }} То же...

Comment: Если JSON.stringify(response)   "array(12) {\n  [0]=>\n  array(3) {\n    [\"order\"]=>\n    string(1) \"1\"\n    [\"isDone\"]=>\n    bool(true)\n    [\"title\"]=>\n    string(41) \"Title1\"\n  }\n  [1]=>...

Comment: это больше похоже на строку :-) вы уверены что вы json отдаете в своем php?

Comment: я бы даже сказал - это **точно** строка. а само содержание похоже на просто дамп переменной

Comment: Вы правы, передавал массив из php без кодировки в json. После json_encode($response); к элементам можно обратится так: pageData[2].isDone

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32346/discussion-between-grundy-and--).